# What does the quadratic form $0.5x^T Ax^T-b^Tx$ find the minimum of?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to work through example 2, from [here](http://torch.ch/docs/five-simple-examples.html#_).

We start by defining a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$:

$\begin{pmatrix} 
1.2054 & 0.6593  &1.2299 & 1.2577 & 1.0083\\
 0.6593 & 0.5179 & 0.5460 & 0.8562 & 0.4608\\
 1.2299 & 0.5460 & 2.6713 & 1.8403 & 1.6162\\
 1.2577 & 0.8562 & 1.8403 & 2.5114 & 1.6419\\
 1.0083 & 0.4608 & 1.6162 & 1.6419 & 1.4266
\end{pmatrix}$.

Next, we define a vector $b$ with random numbers as entries:

$\begin{pmatrix}
 0.0258\\
 0.1957\\
 0.9065\\
 0.3823\\
 0.7864
\end{pmatrix}$

Then, we compute $xs=A^{-1}b$.

Finally, we feed this the quadratic form:

$0.5xs^T Axs^T-b^Txs$

and, with the my numbers, get $-4.46333$, which doesn't appear anywhere in the matrix $A$. So if this is supposed to be an exact minimum, what's it supposed to be an exact minimum of?

Comment: $(x + b/a)^2 = x^2 + 2 x b/a +  b^2/a^2$

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: $||M x||^2 = x^T M^T M x$

Answer (score 1):

I think, while $A$ is a matrix and $b$ is a vector one tries to find a vector $x$ such that $0.5x^T Ax^T-b^Tx$ is minimal. The minimal value of your form might then be $−4.46333$.

Doing so one gets

$$0.5x^TA-b^T =0$$
$$0.5x^TA=b^T$$
$$0.5x^T=b^T A^{-1}$$
$$0.5x = (A^{-1})^Tb$$

I am not sure about all the transposels sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It is the minimum value of the quadratic form $J(x) = 0.5 x^T A x - b^T x$.

Consider the vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ a symmetric positive defined matrix, we have the quadratic form  $J:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, that is a function of $n$ variables.

From Calculus, we know the point of minimum value is a critic point of $J$.
Then, we have to search for $x^*$ such that
$$
\nabla J(x^*) = 0.
$$
It is easy to verify that the gradient of $J$ is given by,
$$
\nabla J(x) = Ax - b.
$$
So we want $x^*$ such that
$$
A x^* - b = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow A x^* = b \quad \Longrightarrow x^* = A^{-1}b.
$$
We can invert the matrix $A$ because it is positive defined and, consequently, non-singular. The linear system has an unique solution.

It remains to be seen now if $x^*$ is actually a point of minimum. But the Hessian matrix of $J(x)$ is $A$ that is positive defined, then  $x^*$ is a point of minimum.

Now the minimum value of $J(x)$ is given by 
$$J(x^*) = 0.5 (x^*)^T A x^* - b^T x^* = 0.5 (A^{-1}b)^T A A^{-1}b - b^T A^{-1}b = -0.5 b^T A^{-1} b$$.

There is no reason for this number appears somewhere in the matrix $A$.

I Hope this helps you.